# How to make use of RIA Services App.config files (without copying settings to web.config)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, web-config, app-config, wcf-ria-services

Even though I link my web-app with my RIA Services.web library, the App.config setting files are never used and I always need to copy the module settings manually to my web.config.

Am I doing something wrong? Should the App.config file be recognised and automatically loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. Configuration settings in app.config files that are part of loaded assemblies will not be loaded by your web application.

Comment: So there is no support for loading them. What is the purpose of the App.config files in a Silverlight app? Thanks

Comment: They behave the same way they would for an ASP.NET application. In this case you only have 1 page (in an ASP.NET sense) so only the single Web.config file is loaded. I don't think there are any tricks you can pull to make app.config files useful.